# How to properly nest flexbox

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I am trying to create a layout that looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/T81PmkE.png)

I can get the screen split in two halves down the middle, and something on the right hand side vertically centered.

However, when i try to nest a flexbox on the right side, i cant get it to spread across the width of the right hand side.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.column {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.row2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.column2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
      test title
  </div>

  <div class="column content">
    <div class="row2">
      <div class="column2">
        abc
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        abc
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        abc
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        abc
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought the justify-content: space-between in row2 would evenly spread the 4 (or some other amount) "abc"s across the width of the right half of the screen, but they just stack up on the left. It seems that the row2 is not filling the width of the parent properly. I'm guessing the justify-content is working but has no width to spread the items across. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is make `.row2` 100% width. I also changed it to `space-around` since that seems more like what you're going for in your screenshot.

```
.row2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.column {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.row2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100%;
}

.column2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
      test title
  </div>

  <div class="column content">
    <div class="row2">
      <div class="column2">
        abc
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        abc
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        abc
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        abc
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to make the "abc" boxes squares, you can use `aspect-ratio: 1`, and to make them as big as they can be inside their container, you can use `flex-grow: 1`. Finally, add a bit of margin to them to give them some spacing. (Technically, you no longer need `space-around` anymore with this method, since the boxes will grow to fill the entire container anyway, unless you set a fixed height for the abc boxes.)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.column {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.row2 {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100%;
}

.column2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px black solid;
  flex-grow: 1;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
      test title
  </div>

  <div class="column content">
    <div class="row2">
      <div class="column2">
        abc
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        abc
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        abc
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        abc
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you know how to make the height equal to the width that results from the space-around so that it forms squares?

Comment: See the second half of my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a flex container will not expand its children to fill up the available space.

You fix this by adding `width: 100%;` to your `.row2` class.

Comment: Thanks. That worked, and in my real code, i noticed i had wrapped an extra div around the row2 in there that was also limiting the width.

Comment: An alternative to `width: 100%` is `flex-grow: 1`. And also, `space-evenly` might get a better result here than `space-between`.